# Interpreting the expected value as an abstract integral?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

My notes contain the following notation

$$E(\theta\mid X) = \int \theta \, df(\theta\mid X) = \int \theta f(\theta\mid X) \, d\theta$$

The first integral looks like a Riemann–Stieltjes integral, although this sequence of equalities does not look correct to me. I thought that the general relation is (non-rigorously)

$$\int f(y)\,dg(y) = \int f(y)g'(y)\,dy$$

which indicates that $df(\theta \mid X)$ in the first line should instead be $dF(\theta \mid X)$, the cumulative <s>density</s> distribution function. Is there an error in the notes or am I missing something in this probabilistic interpretation?

Comment: There is no such thing as a cumulative density function.  "Cumulative" contradicts "density".  Density is what physicists call an "intensive" quantity, whereas anything _cumulative_ is _extensive_ rather than _intensive_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is meant to be:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\theta \mid X) & = \int \theta \;\operatorname d F(\theta\mid X) \tag{capital F}
\\ & = \int \theta \;f(\theta \mid X) \operatorname d \theta \tag{lowercase f}
\end{align}$$